# Transform characters to numbers

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` of two vectors.

```
df <- data.frame(G1=c("b","a","e","d","c"),
                 G2=c("c","d","e","b","a"))
```

You can see that both vectors have the same characters, but in diferent order. I want to convert them into numbers and then compare them.

To compare G2 to G1, G1 must be the reference, so the output will be this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(G1=c("1","2","3","4","5"),
                 G2=c("5","4","3","1","2"))
```

Is there a way to do this?, thanls

Comment: Should the numbers be characters?  Or numerics?

Comment: @Richard Scriven they must be numeric characters

Answer (score 4):

This seems to give your output:

```
df <- data.frame(G1=c("b","a","e","d","c"),
                 G2=c("c","d","e","b","a"))

G1 <- as.character(as.numeric(factor(df$G1,levels=unique(df$G1))))
G2 <- as.character(as.numeric(factor(df$G2,levels=unique(df$G1))))
df2<-data.frame(G1,G2)
df2
#   G1 G2
# 1  1  5
# 2  2  4
# 3  3  3
# 4  4  1
# 5  5  2
```

Note that df2 displays as numeric but in fact is character. Also note that in defining `G2` we use the levels of `df$G1`. This is key.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(G1 = match(df$G1, unique(df$G1)))
df2$G2 <- match(df$G2, unique(df$G1))
df2
#  G1 G2
#1  1  5
#2  2  4
#3  3  3
#4  4  1
#5  5  2
```

Comment: but this presumes there are no repeated elements in G1. If some elements can be repeated then you would need something like `match(df$G1, unique(df$G1))` in the first row of your code.

Comment: @lebatsnok - you're right. I have adjusted my code. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

load CRAN package : hash

```
require("hash")

df <- data.frame(G1=c("b","a","e","d","c"),
                 G2=c("c","d","e","b","a"),
                 stringsAsFactors= FALSE)
```

Determine the column number to be considered as hash key (Eg: Column 1 as below)

```
hashkey <- df[,1]
```

Set unique hash values for the length of a column (Eg: Column 1 as below)

```
hashval <- seq(1, length(df[,1]))
```

Create hash table (associative array) using the hash function

```
h <- hash (keys = hashkey, 
           values = hashval
          )
```

"getvalues" function will extract values for every record in the data frame

The function "values" is part of hash package

```
getvalues <- function(x) {

  vals <- values(h[x], 
                 USE.NAMES = FALSE)
  return(vals)

}
```

Apply "getvalues" function to every record in a data frame

You need to manually change column numbers of "df" data frame to have the effect of getvalues function applied to it. (Eg: Column numbers 1 and 2 as below)

```
df[,1:2] <- data.frame(lapply(df[,1:2],
                              FUN = function(x) { sapply(x,FUN = getvalues )}), 
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df

  G1 G2
1  1  5
2  2  4
3  3  3
4  4  1
5  5  2

str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ G1: int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ G2: int  5 4 3 1 2
```

If you need values in the data frame to be of character type, use this form of getvalues function.

```
getvalues <- function(x) {
  vals <- values(h[x], 
                 USE.NAMES = FALSE)
  return(as.character(vals))
}

str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ G1: chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ G2: chr  "5" "4" "3" "1" ...
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for all your suggestions,
this is what I have done with the original `data.frame`:

```
df$G1.num <- 1:length(df$G1)
df$G2.num <-  match(df$G2,df$G1)
df
```

In this way I get a nice output, where I can see the original terms, plus their numerical designation:

```
  G1 G2 G1.num G2.num
1  b  c      1      5
2  a  d      2      4
3  e  e      3      3
4  d  b      4      1
5  c  a      5      2
```